¿Existe un método para para validar que un string está escrito en mayusculas? JAVASCRIPT
Este método simula una interacción entre una persona y su abuela que no escucha muy bien. La abuelita a cualquier cosa que le digas te responderá gritando: "¡¿EH?! ¡NO TE ESCUCHO, HIJO!" Si le gritas para tratar de escucharte, lo mal interpretará y responderá a gritos. "NO, NO DESDE 1983" Para ir y dejar de hablarle con amor hay que decir "ADIÓS TQM" Finalmente para terminar el programa o dejar de hablar con ella: Tienes que decir tres veces "ADIÓS TQM". Cuando usamos la función para ingresar desde la ventana sería como “Dile algo a tu abuela” y ella te responderá imprimiendo en la consola. El uso de mayúsculas puede dar sentido al tono en el que habla. Finalmente por terminar el programa o dejar de hablar con ella: Tienes que decir tres veces "ADIÓS TQM".
`function dialogo(){
    let mnsj = prompt('Dile algo a tu abuelita')
    if (mnsj = 'ADIOS TQM ADIOS TQM ADIOS TQM') {
        console.log('Adios hijito')
    } else if( mnsj = 'ADIOS TQM'){
        alert('Dejas de hablarle con amor')
        dialogo()
    } else if (mnsj= ((MAYÚSCULAS)) ){


    } else {
        console.log('¡¿EH?! ¡NO TE ESCUCHO, HIJO!')
        dialogo()
    }
}    
dialogo()`


Tienes que usar == o === para comparar, = asigna y siempre devuelve "true" en un if

Puedes convertir el string mayúsculas utilizando toUpperCase() y luego comparar contra el string original. Evidentemente si son iguales, es que el original está con mayusculas


const palabras = ["HOLA","hola","HoLa"];

const isUpperCase = (palabra) => palabra.toUpperCase() === palabra; // Comparas en mayúsculas contra el original

for(const p of palabras){ 
  if(isUpperCase(p)){  
     console.log(p, "Está en mayúsculas");
  }
  else{
     console.log(p, "No está en mayúsculas");
  }
}



